# Using Cron to export data from mysql database to CSV, then getting all it's data to bigquery table

Tags: mysql, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Using Cron to export data from mysql database to CSV, then reading this csv file and getting all it's data to google cloud using bigquery

Hello guys, I have a Mysql database called db_test, and one table in it called members_test(id, name). I'm working on Linux Ubunto OS. I am trying to use cronjob to take data at midnight from this table into a CSV file. Also I want to let bigquery somehow read this csv file and take its data and put them in a table called cloud_members_tab saved on the google cloud platform.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make sure you have your CSV generated correctly (don't rely on MySQL CSV export natively)
2. install `gsutil` and `bq` command line utility
3. upload CSV to Google Cloud Storage

use a shell command like below:

> gsutil cp -j -o="GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M"
>   /tmp/export.csv gs://bucket/export.csv

4. use `bq load`

> bq load --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter="," --null_marker="\N"
>   --allow_quoted_newlines --autodetect --source_format=CSV dataset.tablename gs://bucket/export.csv

Comment: I have already written this .sh file: 


#!/bin/bash

dbUser=root
dbName=db_test
csv_file="/tmp/members.csv"

if [ -f $csv_file ] then
    rm $csv_file
fi

mysql --user=$dbUser --database=$dbName --execute="select * into outfile '$csv_file' Fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' from members;"

Comment: in your answer you have mentioned the dataset and the table but didn't mention the username or password of my google cloud account

Comment: please don't rely on the mySQL CSV output, it won't work as it's not following the standard. You need to write a programming script for it.

Comment: I also have a csv file in my google drive, and I'm trying to take it to a google cloud bucket using cloud shell commands. can you please help

Comment: @HassanHAJJAR can you open new post since it is a different question?